# SQLite symbology export?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, sqlite, qgis-2.18

Trying to make a couple databases which contain everything that needs to be mapped for a few projects. For best conformity it would be great to keep style embedded within the database to enable a simple save as but the only way I can think of it to .qml all the different styles. As there will be >20 layers all in, don't really want a different .qml for each layer, takes up space and less easy!

But the symbology export doesn't ever seem to keep the symbology.

Can it be done?

Can save as different file type but wouldn't know which one is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the layer properties, choose Style > Save Style > in the database.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to save the style in the layers which I had then made into a SQLite Database - this worked when using the layers which had been saved into the database.

Comment: @Belinda it should automatically add the style when you add the layer from the Browser panel in QGIS - this is incredibly handy in PostGIS for our enterprise users...

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to embed a style in a database using ArcGIS Pro? With the aim being to have styles embedded in a database from both QGIS and ArcGIS Pro so that it looks the same in both programs,